# Using VSCode and getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I usually use IDE like IntelliJ but am trying to move to VSCode but I dont understand why the project I'm working on IntelliJ runs fine but when I open that project in VSCode I get that error. I've looked at other answers for this questions but they all mention things such as bin, src, and classpath which I am not very familiar with. I imagine that's if you run java through cmd but I dont. How can I resolve this?

My file in D:\Antonio\Documents\GitLab\ProjectEuler-Java\Solved_Problems

```
package Solved_Problems;

class Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5{

  // Multiples of 3 and 5

  /*
   * 
   * If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we
   * get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23. Find the sum of all the
   * multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.
   *
   */

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int totalsum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
      if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0))
        totalsum += i;
    }

    System.out.println(totalsum);

  }

}
```

Output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.835 seconds
```

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: I think VSCode is great.  On Linux, and Windows; for many things, especially HTML5/CSS3/JS front end work.  But I'd absolutely encourage you to continue using a "Java IDE" for Java work.  My preference is Eclipse.  Look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial).  Be *SURE* to install the "Java Extension Pack"!

Comment: @paulsm4 I have them all installed and still receiving same error. Why not do Java work in VSCode? What are the major differences vs an Java IDE?

Comment: Java *CAN* "work in VSCode".  But if you're "not familiar" with "things such as bin, src, and classpath" ,,, then trust me.  You'll probably be *MUCH* happier and productive in a "Java friendly" IDE like IntelliJ, Netbeans or (my favorite) Eclipse.  My "guess"? Your "Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5.class" file needs to be inside directory "Solved_Problems".  You need to run Java *ABOVE* that directory, and you need to *INCLUDE* it in your classpath.  It sounds like the VSCode debugger is doing this ... but you're not.

Comment: @paulsm4 my only problem with some IDE like IntelliJ is the long startup time and I have it installed on a M.2 SSD. I would like to get familiar with those topics so that I can transition to VSCode. I've been messing with CLASSPATH for the last 3 days but nothing seems to work. I've done the whole javac filename.java then java filename.class (without .class) and nothing.  Also I also use monokai theme on all text editors and IDEs so no I dont like the default colors.

Comment: you could delete the `configurations` content in `launch.json`,and then run it ,let vscode Auto-generated content，if still throw error,press `F1` and input `clean` then select clean the `java language server workspace`

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I tried your suggestion but I got this error now:

```[Running] cd "d:\Antonio\Documents\GitLab\ProjectEuler-Java\Solved_Problems\" && javac Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5.java && java Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5
Error: Could not find or load main class Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5

[Done] exited with code=1 in 1.567 seconds
```

Comment: We are not able to reproduce the issue. Could you maybe share a basic minimal sample that can reproduce this?

Answer (score 0):

you try to this:

`cd d:\Antonio\Documents\GitLab\ProjectEuler-Java\Solved_Problems`

`javac Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5.java`

`cd..`

then

`java Solved_Problems.Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5` (package+class)

Comment: I tried this still got the same error. However I was able to<br/>

```cd d:\Antonio\Documents\GitLab\ProjectEuler-Java\Solved_Problems```<br/>

```java Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5.java```

and get expected results.

Comment: you mean you could run by terminal but could not when press F5 ?

Comment: ```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}"
        },
```

Comment: try to change "mainClass":"${file}" to "mainClass":"Solved_Problems.Problem_001_MultiplesOf3And5"

Comment: I did continues to throw same error. Is there anyway I could configure launch.json to just            

```java filename.java```  

That gives me the output I'm looking for.

Comment: normally, you delete your configuration and run it and it will automatically generate the correct configuration

Comment: do you try to open a new project ?

Comment: Deleted configuration and issue persist. Could it somehow have to do with my CLASSPATH config?

Comment: So I opened a new project that is only one java file and when I clicked Run or pressed F5 it actually worked perfectly. Though the option to right click then click Run throws same error. So what could possibly be wrong in my original project?

Comment: have you try to clean the workspace ?i could not repeat your issue

Comment: and why your project  doesn't have `src`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is resolved for you, but it took me a long time to figure it out too. What I did:

First I created a launch.json file using the Java plugin.
Then I edited the `mainClass` variable to `myfilename.java`. I had the same error as you if I only put `myfilename` in the `mainClass` variable.

As last step you need to modify `classPath` to include whatever .jar you need for the project.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other options posted here work, try locating your java install. If it was altered after VSCode was installed, VSCode may be trying to locate java somewhere other than where it is.

After locating, delete the jdk folder and reinstall java. VSCode should now be functional.